# Function calling in a wrong way (sum of a sequence)

Tags: c, function, sum

So my program reads numbers until the value 0 then it calculates the sum of numbers. Then I have to write a function which displays the sum. Also, my program read a number "y" from keyboard and I need to find the result of the sum/y.For example if the result of the sum is 10 and I enter y=3 the function result should return the result of 10/3.

So after the program display the result of the sum it asks me to enter again values until 0 value then it closes.

```
#include <stdio.h>


// Shows a message with what the program is doing.
void ShowIntroduction(void)
{
    printf("My program finds a sum etc");
}


// find the sum of the numbers enter until 0 value
int sum(void)
{
    int s=0,n;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n > 0)
            s=s+n;
    }
    while(n != 0);


   return s;
}


// show the result
void sumResult(int a)
{
    printf("The sum is %d", a);
}

// find the result of sum/y
double result(int s,int y)
{
        double res;
        res=s/(double)(y);
        return res;
}

int main()
{
    int y;
    scanf("%d",&y);
    ShowIntroduction();
    sumResult(sum());
    result(sum(),y);

    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure I don't call a function in a correct way.

The program displays the sum but not the result of the sum / y

Comment: Because you never told the program to *display* the result.  You probably want an additional `printf`.

Comment: I wrote ``` printf("The result is %f ", result(sum(),y)); ``` but the result is wrong.

Comment: What input are you giving to the program, and what result do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `sum()` twice, one for displaying the sum and one for displaying the average result. But because you let the users enter their values inside of `sum()` you see the behavior you describe.

Just run your program as is and enter two times the same sequence of numbers. Then you should see both the sum and the average. This is just to make you understand your program.

The solution is to store the sum returned by `sum()` in a variable and give its value to `sumResult()` and `result()`.